# What does "as we know it" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is what I read

> Legislation X transformed criminal law as we know it.

Does it mean legislation X transformed criminal law at some point in the past into the one we know today?

Comment: "As we know it" means "In its current or accepted state". It has no relationship to change except as an expression of the current state to which that change may be compared.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose literally it does mean that. But the phrase is hardly ever used literally. It means that the changes were huge, or even fundamental.

Comment: So "as we know" is actually an idiom meaning drastic change ?

Comment: @Doeser No, _as we know it_ does not mean "drastic change". See [**this link.**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/as-we-know-it) (Colin's answer refers to the phrase "legislation A transformed criminal law as we know it", not to the idiom _as we know it._)